# I Can't Sign Up For Admob?

Tags: android, admob

I understand Admob is getting an overhaul, but I don't see why I can't sign up for an Admob account.

I am using my Gmail account, but when I go to https://apps.admob.com/admob/ a red bar at the top of the page shows up saying "An error has occurred. Refresh the page and try again".

I don't even have Adblock downloaded, as I know that helped some people.  Also, my secondary Gmail account seems to be able to proceed on from the first step.  I really think I should be using the same Gmail account that is also used for my Android developers account.

I have contacted support and they say simply open an incognito window (and I have done so), and I made sure some of the network certificates are cleared, and that my extensions were disabled.

Any insight would be appreciated.  The account will be 18 in less than a month if that helps at all, and I also was about to go through the Adsense process (I don't think I actually sent my application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your adsense account go to access and authorization section and click on AdMob account and select current account as preferred account.

Comment: Changed this to the answer, this should still work with legacy.  If not, you can follow my answer above.

Answer (score 5):

An ad blocker can cause this as well. Disable ad blocker and try again.

Answer (score 1):

This may not have been the best place to ask this question but I have seen similar.

Basically, there have been some big revisions to the Admob service, so if you happened to have submitted an application with Adsense, your account may get the error I described above.  The best advice I can give is just to contact the [Help Center](https://support.google.com/admob/?hl=en#topic=4490031)!

Answer (score 1):

i changed my dns server to 8.8.8.8 (google) and that fixed it